# Matlab OOP - Can getter methods have arguments?

Tags: matlab, oop

I`m working on a matlab OOP project where I need to have a getter method with one argument. Since I don`t want to make the problem very specific I want to generalize. So here`s the context:

- I have a 2D spatial object (SpaceObject) with the following fields: X_Pos,Y_Pos and Movement_Model.
- X_Pos and Y_Pos describe the position of the spatial object in the XY plane.
- Movement_Model is an object which describes the movement of the space object in the XY plane. This field is initialized as empty [] so it can be defined or undefined.
- When Movement_Model field object is undefined the convention is that X_Pos and Y_Pos are time invariant. Getting these properties is done implicitly by writing *pos = space_obj.X_Pos*
- When Movement_Model field object is defined the convention is that X_Pos and Y_Pos become time variant. But this time the getter methods need the time value/values in conjuction with the Movement_Model field object to compute the position in space at any time instant. So I want to have something like this: *pos = space_obj.X_Pos* or *pos = space_obj.X_Pos(1)* or *pos = space_obj.X_Pos([1:1:10])* but Matlab getters cannot have other parameters.
- One solution would be to make the time variable internal to the space object but I have strong design constraints to have the time variable external to all objects.
- Another solution would be to have a function instead of a getter named Get_X_Pos but I want to keep consistency with other static objects (for which X_Pos and Y_Pos are time invariant). I want to avoid having mixed signatures like space_obj.Get_X_Pos(1) and other_obj.X_Pos. But this means I need to write the Get_X_Pos function for all other objects even if it is not required.

So the problem here is given by a class property with external dependency. So my questions are:

- Why Matlab doesn`t allow other parameters for getter methods? Is this requirement conflicting with some OOP paradigms? Why?
- How can I solve this issue in an elegant way? Maybe a redesign is required...
  Anyway my problem may seem trivial but I`m looking for a best practice/design since my project will grow large over time. Any help is much appreciated!
  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `getter` method with one (or more arguments) is not a classic `getter` method anymore - it's simply a normal method.

Using a plain method you could implement both use cases:

```
function x_pos = X_Pos(this, t)
    if nargin < 2
        % handle space_obj.X_Pos case
    else
        % handle space_obj.X_Pos(1) case
    end
end
```

The fact that matlab executes functions even if they're referenced without empty brackets then lets you combine both cases:

```
x_static = space_obj.X_Pos
```

or

```
x_at_t1 = space_obj.X_Pos(t1)
```

However I'd personally favour splitting this in two parts to make a clear distinction between the two. E.g. by using `X0_Pos` or something similar for the "static" version of this property and `X_Pos` as the time depenent one. In that case you could e.g. use a dependent property to return `static_obj.X_Pos(0)` for `static_obj.X0_Pos`:

```
function x0_pos = X0_Pos(this)
    x0_pos = this.X_Pos(0);
end
```

Comment: But there is an issue: if there is a property named X_Pos you cannot have a method with this name! I quess the class cannot tell which one you query when you write obj.X_Pos. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, yes of course. I'm not suggesting to use a method and property - but a method instead of the property. Since calling a no-argument method is syntax-wise identical to accessing a property there's no harm done.